# How to listen to an Android variable from React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to emulate the behavior of `useEffect` where it listens to a react variable and then triggers other behavior when that variable changes. However, I want it to listen to a variable in one of my java classes from the android part of my program. I know I can pass a variable through @ReactMethod but then I have to call that method explicitly, rather than just listening to the variable.

I can access the variable `x` by calling `MyClass.x` currently in React, but the value never changes from what it is initialized to be.

What is the right way to listen to the android variable so I can tie it to a useEffect function and trigger behavior when it changes?

I've tried following the instructions here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript

But when I call `getJSModule`, it says `Tried to access a JS module before the React instance was fully set up`.

I've read that I should check if `reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()` and if not, then don't send. That keeps the app from breaking, but the problem is it's always `false`. No matter what, even though React is clearly running (and I get logs from it etc) `hasActiveCatalystInstance` is always false.

I've tried using `context` passed into my java constructor, `getReactApplicationContext`, a few more other means as well...none of them ever yield a true `hasActiveCatalystInstance`.

Here is some example code:

```
public class MyModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    MyServer _server;

    MyModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);

        try {
            _server = new Server();
            sendHasValidServer(true);
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            sendHasValidServer(false);
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void addListener(String eventName) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ADDING LISTENER");
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void removeListeners(Integer count) {
        Log.e(TAG, "REMOVING LISTENER");
    }

    private void sendHasValidServer(boolean valid) {

        ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext) getReactApplicationContext();
        
        if (reactContext == null)
            return;

        if(!reactContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No active catalyst");
            return;
        }

        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("hasValidServer", valid + "");
        // Get EventEmitter from context and send event to it
        reactContext
            .getJSModule(MyModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit("onHasValidServer", params);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript

Comment: @Abe I've now implemented that, but it always gives that react context hasn't been initialized (even though it has) and hasActiveCatalystInstance is always false. I have a valid ReactApplicationContext object, but because hasActiveCatalystInstance is always false, it breaks when it tries to send. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: Haven't seen that no. Can you add more about how you're using the object and the method to your post? What points to context having been initialized?

Comment: @Abe I've added some more details to the question, is it what you need?